# Java StringBuilder append to specific line

Tags: java

Is there any way to append a string to the end of a specific line in a StringBuilder object? 
Here's an example output:

```
Test
X15 = 3
X18 = 6
X21 = 2
...
...
```

I would like to be able to append a string to let's say the line containing X21, therefore the output would be:

```
Test
X15 = 3
X18 = 6
X21 = 2 This is a test
...
...
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're going to need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: That's not really how "appending" works. You can string replace that line with the new content

Comment: @cricket_007 StringBuilder.replace() requires an index start and end, how can I replace the line without knowing the index? Unless there's a way I can find the index where X21 occurs.

Comment: `indexOf("X21")`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it doesn't take into account that there might be something printed after "X21". Which could result in: "X21 This is a test = 2"

Comment: Maybe I can loop from that index until I find the index of the next linebreak /n and insert the string before it?

Comment: Figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an easy way. One thing you have to know, it's that StringBuilder is not an array os String. It's a string an array of char but the difference with String is that it's dynamic.

When you append a string "XX" your StringBuilder become "XX". If you add another string let's say "PP", you StringBuilder become "XXPP". SO it's not an easy way to append something to a specific. I think that I understand very well your question.

To make it done, one thing consist to create an ArrayList of StringBuilder, like that, see bellow:

```
List<StringBuilder> allString = new ArrayList<>();
//for line 1
allString.add(new StringBuiler());
//for line 2
allString.add(new StringBuiler());
```

Now if you want to add something to specific line, you just have to do:

```
allString.get(0).append("X21");
allString.get(0).append(" TEST");
//line 1 become X21 TEST
```

For show all your text, you just have to iterate your List and to print StringBuilder to console or another flow.

I hope I help you.

Cheers